# How to enable macOS dark mode on PyQt 5.12.2?

Tags: python, macos, pyqt, pyqt5

For example, [this page](https://www.learnpyqt.com/blog/macos-mojave-dark-mode-support-pyqt5122/) claims that the newest version of PyQt5 should give me automatic dark mode for macOS Mojave, without changing a single thing on my end... Except that it doesn't.

Consider this simple example (can be copy-pasted into terminal):

```
exec("""\nfrom PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets\n\nclass Ui_MainWindow(object):\n    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):\n        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")\n        MainWindow.resize(674, 371)\n        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)\n        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")\n        self.gridLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)\n        self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 601, 281))\n        self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName("gridLayoutWidget")\n        self.mpl_layoutBox = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)\n        self.mpl_layoutBox.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)\n        self.mpl_layoutBox.setObjectName("mpl_layoutBox")\n        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)\n        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 300, 113, 32))\n        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")\n        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)\n\n        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)\n        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)\n\n    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):\n        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate\n        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))\n        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))\n\nif __name__ == "__main__":\n    import sys\n\n    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)\n    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()\n    ui = Ui_MainWindow()\n    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)\n    MainWindow.show()\n    sys.exit(app.exec_())\n""")
```

What must I do to enable dark mode?

Comment: Just running this script on a system with a `pip install pyqt==5.12.2` works in light and dark mode, even when switching it at the system preferences level, without needing to compile it into an .app.

Comment: Strange. Not for me! Does having it in a venv make a difference? Edit: nope.

Comment: Didn't work from a virtualenv. That seems to be the difference here.

Comment: Doesn't work with system-wide interpreter for me. Added one-liner to test it.

Comment: Which system-wide interpreter? And did you verify that the system-wide interpreter has the same version of pyqt5?

Comment: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin//python3` and `>>> import PyQt5.QtCore
>>> PyQt5.QtCore.PYQT_VERSION_STR
'5.12.2'`

Comment: Both of my python 3 interpreters were built by pyenv on Mojave. Notwithstanding your own answer/comment, this may be why I'm seeing different results to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it wasn't apparent to me that it must be compiled to an .app first, and then `NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance` should be added to the top-level `Info.plist`, but that fixed it.